# Is it harmful to leave my bird uncovered at night?

Tags: birds, sleep

My pet bird has her cage covered at night. If I am going on vacation, my best option is to have a friend check on her every day. This means she would be left uncovered since it would be a lot to ask for someone to check on her first thing in the morning as well as in the evening.

She is in a room with a window and the lights would be off, so she'd have a natural light cycle.

Would this be harmful to her? I have seen her take naps during the day, however each night she asks me (in her own birdy way) to put her cover on.

Comment: Have you tried leaving her uncovered before and observed her reaction?

Comment: @SerenaT if I am not home for one evening she is left uncovered and she seems fine the next morning. If I return home late at night when she is uncovered, she also seems fine. Maybe I'll try leaving her uncovered when I'm home and see how she is. She's never been uncovered longer than a day though.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would advise, try it out for a few days and check for signs of stress. Some birds do not mind it others can not sleep peacefully without the cover.
Maybe you can even post what you find out as an answer to your question :)

Comment: @SerenaT what signs of stress should I be looking for?

Comment: Stress Bars, Feather Picking and/or Self Mutilation, Aggression, Loss of Appetite, Change in Vocalization, Repetitive Behavior, Fear, Boredom - these are from here https://www.thesprucepets.com/signs-of-stress-in-pet-birds-390437, where I also found the article that suggested trying out leaving your bird uncovered if you are unsure - https://www.thesprucepets.com/should-birdcage-be-covered-at-night-390338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cage cover is a way to ensure that there is darkness so that your bird can get a proper amount of sleep. If there is enough darkness without a cage cover, then a cage cover is not necessary.

Birds do not do well with sudden changes to their routine, though. If leaving the cage cover off will cause a change in the number of hours of darkness each day, try to ease the change in gradually.

Here's some useful information about avian lighting needs from the avian vet that my birds visit: https://azeah.com/birds-cockatiels-cockatoos-macaws-parakeets-parrots/providing-right-light

As for your bird taking naps every day, let you bird be an example for us all!

Answer (score 1):

Our 2 African Grey parrots are in the same situation . Apparently leaving them uncovered from time to time does not seem to affect them. Although one says "good night" every evening until they are covered; I don't know what happens when we are not home.